# Reverse induction for $n^3 - n$ is divisible by 3

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

a) First I proved the first part of this exercise which states to prove the statement $P(n) = n^3 -n$ is divisible by 3 for only positive integers with induction.

$P(1) = 0 \Rightarrow$ multiple of $3$

I.H.: Let n be a postive arbitrary number so that P(n) is divisible by 3.

$\begin{align}
P(n+1) & = (n+1)^3 - (n + 1) \\
& = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 - n - 1 \\
& = 3n(n + 1) + n^3 - n \\
& = 3n(n+ 1) + P(n) 
\end{align}$

Now I got stuck with what seems to be the end of this induction proof. I don't know how to get rid of the 2.

b) Proof the previous statement for negative integers but with reverse induction.

I don't know what this really implies. Does it mean you just need to do the same thing as I almost did above but in reverse and for the negative numbers???

c) Proof that the negative case also directly correlates with the positive case with a little bit of algebra.

I don't know how to do this because I'm not done yet. 
d) Proof the statement also directly without induction. I've done this in 3 cases.

$\text{n= 3k with k $\in \mathbb N$
}$

$(3k)^3 - 3k= 27k^3 - 3k= 3( 9k^3 - k)= 3m$ with $m= 9k^3-k$ and m $\in \mathbb N$

$n = 3k \pm 1$:

$(3k \pm 1)^3 - (3k \pm 1)= 3 \cdot(9k^3 \pm 3k^2) = 3m$ with $m= 9k^3 \pm 3k^2$
and $m \in \mathbb N$

I think this should be alright.

Please correct it if it's wrong.

Comment: $P(n+1)=(n+1)^3-\color{red}(n+1\color{red})$.

Comment: Oops I'll edit that. Stupid mistake.

Comment: now on to the 2nd part. Does reverse induction just litteraly mean doing this proof in reverse but for negative numbers in hoc casu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: this is much simplier $$n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$$

Comment: Since when were your answers becoming more helpful?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really answer the problem of induction.... :-/

Comment: this is really true. but why induction?

Comment: Idk, most of the question shouts induction to me.

Comment: It's asked in question d).

Comment: Is part d correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, `sum[k<n](k^2+k)` equals `(n^3-n)/3`, and it is obviously an integer.

Second, `n^3-n` denotes an odd function, so if for n it is an integer, then for -n it is the opposite integer.