# Induction in reverse

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

So the statement that I have to prove is as follows $P(n)=n^3 -n$ is divisible by $3$.

Now I have to prove this with backwards induction for all negative numbers but I've already done the same thing but with "straight" induction for all positive numbers.

Do I need to start from the case $P(n+1)$ and go from there to $P(1)$ or $P(-1)$?

Likewise:

$\begin{align}
P(n+1) & = (n+1)^3 - (n+1) \\
& = n^3 + 3\cdot n^2 + 3 \cdot n + 1 - n + 1      \\
& = 3n(n+1) + n^3 - n 
\end{align}$

$\text{I.H.: So let's suppose the above statement holds for any}$ $n \in \mathbb { Z_0^{-}} $

Then I don't know anymore how to continue.

For the 2<sup>nd</sup> part I need to prove that the case of the negative numbers directly follows out of the positive case.

I don't know how to get this part because I'm not sure of the previous case.

Please help me out.

Comment: `prove that the case of the negative numbers directly follows out of the positive case` $P(n) = -P(-n)\,$.

Comment: So what I've done in the first part of the proof is correct?

Comment: If you have settled the nonnegative case, the negative case is settled too, because $(-n)^3-(-n)=-(n^3-n)$. You don't need to prove the negative case separately by mathematical induction.

Comment: @AnonymousI `I've already done the same thing but with "straight" induction for all positive numbers` You don't show *this* part in the posted question. Point is that you do not need any induction, in reverse or otherwise, for the negative case - it simply follows from the positive one.

Comment: @user1551: That was the task. I've proven the nonnegative case and then I needed to prove the negative case with reverse induction.

Comment: @AnonymousI `then I needed to prove the negative case with reverse induction` This is not what you wrote in the question: `prove that the case of the negative numbers **directly follows** out of the positive case`.

Comment: @AnonymousI But there is a difference between using backward induction to show it for all negative numbers (that will still be an inductive proof), and showing that the negative case immediately follows from the positive case (which is *not* an inductive proof).... so which is it?

Comment: @dxiv: Yeah that's the 2nd part of the exercise. See the following link for the very first part of the exercise. Then this part comes.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425688/reverse-induction-for-n3-n-is-divisible-by-3

Comment: @Bram28: It's both

Comment: Let's summarize the whole exercise.

Comment: a) Prove that $P(n) = n^3 -n$ is divisible by 3 for positive integers with induction.

Comment: b) Prove that this is also the case for all negative numbers but with backward induction.

Comment: c) Prove that the negative case follows directly of the positive case with a little bit of algebra

Comment: And d) Prove that the expression also follows directly without using induction.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion

Comment: @AnonymousI Ah! OK, for a) you're almost there: since by I.H P(n) is divisible by $3$, and since $3n(n+1)$ is clearly divisible by $3$ as well, it follows that $P(n+1)$ is divisible by $3$. For b), see my Answer below for what you need to do, and for c) see several comments in thread

Comment: @Bram28: Yeah I've noticed your hint. I should have started with n = -1 and go on from there.

Comment: @AnonymousI Yes, you can start at $0$ or $-1$ .. both will work as a base. And for the step do something similar as for the step in the positive case, but instead of going from $n$ to $n+1$ you need to go from $n$ to $n-1$.

Comment: So $n$ is still the induction hypothesis right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show that it holds for all negative numbers by backwards induction (your part b)), show that it holds for $n = 0$ (or maybe start at $n=-1$), and then show that anytime it holds for some $n$, it also holds for $n-1$

For part d): $n^3-n = n(n^2-1) = n(n+1)(n-1) = (n-1)n(n+1)$. Since these are $3$ consecutive integers, one of them will be divisible by $3$

Comment: Did you notice my solution for part a) and d) in my other question?

Comment: Maybe I already solved those parts.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425688/reverse-induction-for-n3-n-is-divisible-by-3

Comment: @AnonymousI for part a) you're almost there: use the I.H that $P(n)$ is divisible by $3$.  Your part d) is not very clear: doing algebra with that $\pm$ is dangerous. ... Better is to work out $n = 3k+1$ and $n=3k-1$ separately.

Comment: @Bram28: I've done that for part a) . See I.H. (Induction hypothesis) in the link. And for part d) I agree with you about that. It's also a lot more organized in your way.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: What do you mean by that? Is it due to some points I didn't give you?

Comment: @AnonymousI No. not for that. thnks.  no problem .

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll let it slide than

Comment: @AnonymousI I wouldn't consider the method above for $(d)$ to count as "not using induction" since the lemma invoked is normally proved by inductive methods. Rather you could note that $\, n^3-n = 3{n+1\choose 3}\,$ and use the fact that binomial coefficients are integers. For the first part it is easier to proceed as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

$$P (n-1)=(n-1)^3-(n-1) $$
$$=(n-1)\Bigl ((n-1)^2-1\Bigr) $$
$$=(n-1)(n-1+1)(n-1-1)$$
$$=(n-2)(n-1)n $$

=product of three consecutive integers.
One of them is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I only can accept one answer. Sorry but Bram's answer is fully explained than yours. But your hint helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

if $n<0$ we have $n^3−n=-(\vert{n}\vert^3-\vert{n}\vert)$, $\vert{n}\vert=1,2, 3...$.

Comment: i.e. it's an *odd* function $f(-n) = -f(n),\,$ being a linear combination of odd functions to odd powers.

Answer (score 2):

If you prove a base case that $P(n)$ for $n= k$

And you prove positive induction step that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ then via induction you have proven this for all $n \ge k$.

And if you prove negative induction step that $P(n) \implies P(n-1)$ then via induction you have proven this for all $n \le k$.

And if you prove *both* positive and negative induction then you have proven it for all $n \ge k$ **AND** all $n \le k$ or in other words for *all* integers.

The neat thing about this is you can choose any base value you like. (But you *do* have to choose one.)

Ex:

Let $P(n) = 3|n^3 - n$

Base case:  Let $n = 13$ then $13^3 - 13 = 2184=3*728$.

*Dual* Induction step.

Assume $P(n)$ so $3|n^3 - n$  and $n^3 - n = 3k$ for some integer $k$.

$(n\pm 1)^3 - (n\pm 1) = (n^3 \pm 3n^2+ 3n \pm 1) - (n\pm 1) = n^3 \pm 3n^2 +2n$

$= n^3 - n + 3n \pm 3n^2 = 3k + 3n \pm 3n^2= 3(k+n \pm n^2)$.

So $3|(n\pm 1)^3 - (n\pm 1)$ so $P(n\pm 1)$.

So by induction $P(n)$ holds for all $n \ge 13$ and $P(n)$ holds for all $n \le 13$.

So $P(n)$ holds for all integers.

Comment: I already understood the question but thanks for making it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ You've shown $\,3\mid P(n\!+\!1)-P(n)\,$ thus $\,3\mid P(n\!+\!1)\iff 3\mid P(n),\,$ and this *bidirectional* inference yields the sought induction step in *both* directions.

**Remark** $ $ Generally if $\,p(n)\,$ is true $\color{#c00}\Leftarrow\!\color{#0a0}\Rightarrow p(n\!+\!1)$ is true, $ $ then $p(n)$ is true for *all* integers $n$ $\iff p(n)$ is true for *some* integer $a$, since $p(n)\color{#0a0}\Rightarrow p(n\!+\!1)\,$ allows us to *ascend* truth of $p(a)$ to all integers $>a\,$ by normal induction, $ $ and $\,p(n)\color{#c00}\Leftarrow p(n\!+\!1)\,$ allows us to *descend* truth of $p(a)$ to all integers $< a\,$ by reverse induction. $ $ Above is the case $\,p(n)\, :=\, 3\mid n^3-n\,$ and e.g. $\,a=0.$

Comment: I've already finished this proof. But the other you commented I didn't.

Comment: @AnonymousI Are you concerned with "finishing" proofs or learning mathematics?

Comment: Both. I've got a lot of proofs to deal with ;) I'm still at exercise 22 and I need to go till 47.

Comment: @AnonymousI Exercises like this are usually designed to help you learn some general method by working through various special cases (see my Remark above). You won't always gain such insight if you settle for the first method you find to finish the proof.

Comment: I agree only I find myself in an unpleasant situation where I need to learn a lot of maths and other sciences as fast as possible. From group theory to calculus to general physics to informatics and discrete maths and some other disciplines.